# Android - Dagger not generating DaggerModelComponent.create()

Tags: java, android, kotlin, dependency-injection, dagger

I'm following these tutorials here trying to learn dagger.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wJkHYBf8VkA

In my activity, I'm trying to call DaggerModelComponent.create() after rebuilding my project and it is unresolved.

Heres my model class:

```
class Car @Inject constructor(engine: Engine, wheels: Wheels) {

fun drive(){
    Log.d("Car", "driving...")
}}
```

My component interface:

```
@Component interface CarComponent {

fun getCar() : Car }
```

And my activity:

```
private lateinit var car: Car

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val component = DaggerCarComponent.create()
    car.drive()
}
```

I also have models for engine and wheels :

```
class Engine @Inject constructor()
```

and

```
class Wheels @Inject constructor()
```

This is what is not working in my activity:

```
val component = DaggerCarComponent.create()
```

Apparently, Dagger is supposed to generate this class but I don't think it is.

These are the dependency imports in my app build.grale

```
implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.25.2'
annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.25.2'
```

Am I missing something? Perhaps I'm doing something wrong in Kotlin, I'm following a tutorial in Java.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution! For Kotlin, apparently it's better to use kapt over annotationProcessor. So adding:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
```

and

```
kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.25.2'
```

to app build.gradle fixed the issue.

Comment: `apparently it's better to use kapt over annotationProcessor` well, kapt stands for:`Kotlin Annotation processing tool` :)

Comment: good job on finding your own solution though. and (a late) welcome to stack overflow

Comment: Thank you! Learning everyday haha